# How to learn xInput and gesture programming in Linux (GTK+)

Tags: linux, user-interface, gesture-recognition, tablet-pc, xinput

**Ramble**: I have been goggling for the past ~week trying to get information on tablet programming for Linux.  I am currently a student tasked with making a tablet application (mobile but tablet is the preferred device).  I am allowed to program with Linux however the class instruction is based on Microsoft XP tablet input "Inking."  I however would like to learn how to write a similar app in Linux ( I am going to attempt to make a gesture GUI for kismet [probably tie in air crack too, mostly just run scripts]).

**Problem**: My problem however is that the I cannot find any opensource gesture engines or similar tools to inking as far as Linux goes.  I know that communities hate n00b questions but can you point me to some n00b xInput programming tutorials that include gestures.  The best I found is [how to doodle with a bitmap backing](http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-23.html).

I'm sorry for n00bing out here, really I'm usually able to fend for my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I don't know much, but I am moved by your anti-n00bness.

http://www.x.org/wiki/XOrgInputDriverSpec
It doesn't look like it's implemented yet, but there is some hope!

https://launchpad.net/canonical-multitouch <- canonical recently announced this, so there's not that much work yet

I don't know, man. You've got a tough question...